# Displaying png files from R into spotfire

Tags: r, image, dynamic, spotfire

I want to pass data from Spotfire to R and then display the plot constructed by R.

 What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a data function with inputs and outputs, and the specific PNG data needs to be returned as a binary label.

Some details: http://spotfire.tibco.com/tips/2014/02/25/dynamically-displaying-images-in-a-text-area/

Answer (score 1):

I’ve figured out the trick of putting images into Spotfire.   It’s not hard if you follow these directions, but it’s done in a way very different from how you guess you would do it in Spotfire, and that’s why it took me awhile to figure out.

Here’s an overview of how to do it. You create a DocumentProperty which is a binary object, you write some Spotfire code that gives a value to that Document Property, and you display that binary object using a Spotfire Property Control of the “Label” type.

The confusing parts are that you DON’T use the Spotfire “Insert Image” tool at all, and that you DON’T use the filename generated inside the R code in Spotfire at all.  Once you get used to the idea that the two most obvious ways you think you would approach the problem in Spotfire are entirely useless and wrong, you can make some progress.

I’ll leave out the spiderplot specifics because the code’s pretty long.

Here’s what you do.

1)  Create a document Property in Spotfire of type “Binary”, e.g., “imageThatGoesBackToSpotfire”
2)  You write some R code that generates an image and writes it to a file:

```
# get a temporary directory name on the local machine.  You wouldn’t need to do this is you were just
# going to run it on your own, but you need to do it if you intend to let anybody else run it on their own machine.
tempfilebase = tempfile()
# take the tempfilebase and prepend it to a filename.
myFilename<-“someFileName.jpg”
myFullFilename <- paste(tempfilebase,myFilename,sep="")
#open a jpeg
jpeg(filename=myFullFileName)
# generate the image, however you normally would in R
plot(input)
# close the file
dev.off
# open a connection to that file.
myConnection<-file(myFullFileName,open=”rb”)
imageThatGoesBackToSpotfire<- data.frame(r=readBin(myConnection, what="raw", n=(file.info(myFullFileName)$size)))
close(myConnection)
```

3)  Run your R script, above.  Select some columns that are the “input” to the plot, and make the R script return outputs to the “imageThatGoesBackToSpotfire” DocumentProperties.
4)  Create a text area in Spotfire.
5)  Insert a Property Control into the text area of type “label”.   (Click on the icon that’s circled in the picture below). This opens a dialog,

Comment: You left us hanging... It's pretty self explanatory after 'This opens a dialog', but I don't have the reputation to finish your answer. The rest of your answer was exactly what I needed.